# What decides that my app is marked as unmanaged?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

I have an app consisting of Apex classes in a developer account. I built a package, logged into my partner account and selected that package.

After doing so, text appears saying

> > License:
> >     Unmanaged - can't be licensed

I read that unmanaged is more for one time code and cannot be upgraded easily, whereas managed we can release updates to the app.

How do I set that I want my app to be managed?

Answer (score 8):

To create a managed package,first you will need to create a namespace for your org .

Note that once you choose a namespace you cannot change it .

Once you have namespaced an org you can create a managed package application from the package manager .Note that if you do not namespace an org ,you will never get an option to make a package managed .